Firease error i the firebase auth login phone number
SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null
I/flutter (28101): Error: This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.
3
I/ViewRootImpl@3fe8718[MainActivity](28101): onDisplayChanged oldDisplayState=2 newDisplayState=2
i have try so many soultion and my buid grade have alredy this
dependencies { implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-safetynet:16.0.0' }


Firebase has a new requirement to add either firebase appcheck, play integrety or have a reCapta check to prevent bots from sending OTPs so for release build you need to integrate either reCaptcha of firebase app check. You can have a look at this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/phone-auth

can you please provide the code to help me out

i am not using the web i am integrating this in the mobile app

https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/default-providers you can use this for appcheck it should work
